# Scheme, N-queens optimization strategies SICP chapter 2

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp, mit-scheme, n-queens

SICP contains an partially complete example of the n-queens solutions, by walking a tree of every possible queen placement in the last row, generating more possible positions in the next row to combine the results so far, filtering the possibilities to keep only ones where the newest queen is safe, and repeating recursively.

This strategy blows up after about n=11 with a maximum recursion error.

I've implemented an alternate strategy that does a smarter tree-walk from the first column, generating possible positions from a list of unused rows, consing each position-list onto an updated list of yet-unused rows. Filtering those pairs considered safe, and recursively mapping over these pairs for the next column. This doesn't blow up (so far) but n=12 takes a minute and n=13 takes about 10 minutes to solve.

```
(define (queens board-size)
 (let loop ((k 1) (pp-pair (cons '() (enumerate-interval 1 board-size))))
   (let ((position (car pp-pair))
         (potential-rows (cdr pp-pair)))
    (if (> k board-size) 
        (list position)
        (flatmap (lambda (pp-pair) (loop (++ k) pp-pair)) 
         (filter (lambda (pp-pair) (safe? k (car pp-pair))) ;keep only safe
          (map (lambda (new-row) 
                (cons (adjoin-position new-row k position) 
                      (remove-row new-row potential-rows))) ;make pp-pair
           potential-rows))))))) 
;auxiliary functions not listed
```

Not really looking for code, but a simple explanation of a strategy or two that's less naive and that clicks well with a functional approach.

Comment: What do you mean by 'blows up'?  If it is that the Scheme implementation fails, what implementation are you using?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2595132/1286639

Comment: @GoZoner,The maximum recursion error kicks in at n 11 or greater, but not for n 10 or less. Using Mit-scheme,

Comment: You can increase the stack size for mit-scheme; doing so will avoid the recursion error that you are seeing.  Try `mit-scheme --stack <number-of-1024-blocks>`.  I know, this doesn't answer your algorithm question.

Comment: In the video lectures Hal Abelson used this problem to demostrate streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer you a simplification of your code, so it may run a little bit faster. We start by renaming some variables for improved readability (YMMV),

```
(define (queens board-size)
 (let loop ((k 1) 
            (pd (cons '() (enumerate-interval 1 board-size))))
   (let ((position (car pd))
         (domain   (cdr pd)))
    (if (> k board-size) 
        (list position)
        (flatmap (lambda (pd) (loop (1+ k) pd)) 
         (filter (lambda (pd) (safe? k (car pd))) ;keep only safe NewPositions
          (map (lambda (row) 
                (cons (adjoin-position row k position)  ;NewPosition
                      (remove-row row domain))) ;make new PD for each Row in D
               domain)))))))                            ; D
```

Now, ***`filter f (map g d) == flatmap (\x->let {y=g x} in [y | f y]) d`*** (using a bit of Haskell syntax there), i.e. we can *fuse* the `map` and the `filter` into one `flatmap`:

```
        (flatmap (lambda (pd) (loop (1+ k) pd)) 
         (flatmap (lambda (row)                   ;keep only safe NewPositions
               (let ( (p (adjoin-position row k position))
                      (d (remove-row row domain)))
                 (if (safe? k p) 
                     (list (cons p d)) 
                     '())))
            domain))
```

then, ***`flatmap h (flatmap g d) == flatmap (h <=< g) d`*** (where `<=<` is right-to-left Kleisli composition operator, but who cares), so we can fuse the two `flatmap`s into just one, with

```
        (flatmap 
            (lambda (row)                         ;keep only safe NewPositions
                (let ((p (adjoin-position row k position)))
                  (if (safe? k p)
                    (loop (1+ k) (cons p (remove-row row domain)))
                    '())))
            domain)
```

so the simplified code is

```
(define (queens board-size)
 (let loop ((k        1) 
            (position '())
            (domain   (enumerate-interval 1 board-size)))
    (if (> k board-size) 
        (list position)
        (flatmap 
            (lambda (row)                         ;use only the safe picks
              (if (safe_row? row k position)      ;better to test before consing
                (loop (1+ k) (adjoin-position row k position)
                             (remove-row row domain))
                '()))
            domain))))
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense combining operations that recurse down the cdr of a list together. Thanks.  I'm also thinking replace domain with an list of domains starting a k long, and remove-row with a function that marks off the rows and diagonals in the rest of the board, removing the need for the safe test,

Comment: @WorBlux you can try representing domains as balanced trees, not lists, for the reduced update time. Using *vectors* to represent domains, update is the fastest, but you would have to copy the vectors, and copy might by O(n); with trees you make an updated copy in the same O(log n) time as the mutation takes. But `n` is very small (8, 10, 13), so both are worth checking. Whether maintaining diagonals versus making few simple math ops is worth it, is also unclear. Bratko did it, though in Prolog.

Comment: @WorBlux re trees, the goal is speeding up `remove-row`. You could perhaps save some cycles by combining it with the picking of possibilities from domain, at the price of precomputing all this structure: in Haskell it's [`pick`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14877448/849891). Of course in Scheme it must be generated efficiently, in [top-down](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13256555/849891), [TRMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) fashion. Knowing the length of domain list in advance might help.

Comment: oops, missed the tag "mit-scheme", re: the edit. indeed the code worked there AFAICR. still, it's better for the code to be compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with a second time around. Not sure it's terribly much faster though. Quite a bit prettier though.

```
(define (n-queens n)
  (let loop ((k 1) (r 1) (dangers (starting-dangers n)) (res '()) (solutions '()))
    (cond ((> k n) (cons res solutions))
          ((> r n) solutions)
          ((safe? r k dangers) 
           (let ((this (loop (+ k 1) 1 (update-dangers r k dangers) 
                             (cons (cons r k) res) solutions)))
             (loop k (+ r 1) dangers res this)))
          (else (loop k (+ r 1) dangers res solutions)))))
```

Big thing is  using a let statement to serialize recursion, limiting depth to n. Solutions come out backwards (could probably fix by going n->1 instead of 1->n on r and k) but a backwards set is the same set as the frowards set.

```
(define (starting-dangers n)
  (list (list)
        (list (- n))
        (list (+ (* 2 n) 1))))
;;instead of terminating in null list, terminate in term that cant threaten
```

small improvement, a danger can come from a row, a down diagonal, or and up diagonal, keep track of each as the board evolves.

```
(define (safe? r k dangers)
   (and (let loop ((rdangers (rdang dangers)))
           (cond ((null? rdangers) #t)
                 ((= r (car rdangers))
                  #f)
                 (else (loop (cdr rdangers)))))
        (let ((ddiag (- k r)))
           (let loop ((ddangers (ddang dangers)))
              (if (<= (car ddangers) ddiag)
                  (if (= (car ddangers) ddiag)
                      #f
                      #t)
                  (loop (cdr ddangers)))))
        (let ((udiag (+ k r)))
           (let loop ((udangers (udang dangers)))
              (if (>= (car udangers) udiag)
                  (if (= (car udangers) udiag)
                      #f
                      #t)
                  (loop (cdr udangers)))))))
```

medium improvement in the change of format, only needing to do one comparison to check vs prior two. Don't think keeiping diagonals sorted cost me anything, but I don't think it saves time either.

```
(define (update-dangers r k dangers)
  (list
     (cons r (rdang dangers))
     (insert (- k r) (ddang dangers) >)
     (insert (+ k r) (udang dangers) <))) 

 (define (insert x sL pred)
   (let loop ((L sL))
      (cond ((null? L) (list x))
            ((pred x (car L))
             (cons x L))
            (else (cons (car L)
                        (loop (cdr L)))))))

(define (rdang dangers)
  (car dangers))
(define (ddang dangers)
  (cadr dangers))
(define (udang dangers)
  (caddr dangers))
```